# Project to show the path of moving object

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video-processing

I have a project in which I have to show the path of a moving object from a video in a single image. How should I go about with this one as I am new to image processing and Matlab.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way would be to load the video as individual images. Afterwards, after segmentation or whatever needs to be done for your specific problem, you have to save the position of the object in each image.

Once you have saved all positions in a matrix you will be able to record and visualize a trajectory.